# Is it possible to delegate the authentication of a Facebook business account to external idp (e.g. Keycloak);

Tags: facebook, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, idp

I'm seeking to delegate the authentication of our company's Facebook Business Account to our external Identity Provider (Keycloak). Specifically, when a user attempts to sign in via the Facebook UI to access our business account, we'd like them to be redirected to our IdP (Keycloak). If the authentication is successful, they should gain access to the business account; otherwise, access should be denied. I'm wondering if Facebook offers the capability to delegate this authentication to an external IdP, and if so, how can it be implemented?

I've reviewed Facebook's documentation regarding Business Account authentication but couldn't find a solution for delegating the authentication process to an external IdP like Keycloak